# Fix FxCop Rule: Enumerations should be strongly typed

Tags: c#, fxcop

I have defined a class named StringResourceCollection.
My Class Declaration is as follows:

```
namespace EPGObjectModel.IDE
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    public class StringResourceCollection : CollectionBase, IEnumerator
    {
        #region Fields

        private int index = -1;

        #endregion Fields

        #region Properties

        public object Current
        {
            get { return this.List[index]; }
        }

        #endregion Properties

        #region Indexers

        public EPGString this[string index]
        {
            get
            {
                Reset();
                while (this.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (((EPGString)Current).StringId == index || ((EPGString)Current).StringName.Equals(index))
                        return (EPGString)Current;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        #endregion Indexers

        #region Methods

        public int Add(EPGString item)
        {
            try
            {
                return List.Add(item);
            }
            catch(Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
        }

        public void Modify(string id, EPGString resourceToModify)
        {
            EPGString stringRes = this[id];
            stringRes.DeletePermission = resourceToModify.DeletePermission;
            stringRes.ModifyPermission = resourceToModify.ModifyPermission;
            stringRes.StringInputLanguage = resourceToModify.StringInputLanguage;
            stringRes.StringLanguage = resourceToModify.StringLanguage;
            stringRes.StringName = resourceToModify.StringName;
            stringRes.StringText = resourceToModify.StringText;
        }

        public void Modify(EPGString resourceToModify)
        {
            EPGString stringRes = this[resourceToModify.StringName];
            if (stringRes == null)
                return;
            stringRes.DeletePermission = resourceToModify.DeletePermission;
            stringRes.ModifyPermission = resourceToModify.ModifyPermission;
            stringRes.StringInputLanguage = resourceToModify.StringInputLanguage;
            stringRes.StringLanguage = resourceToModify.StringLanguage;
            stringRes.StringName = resourceToModify.StringName;
            stringRes.StringText = resourceToModify.StringText;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            this.index++;
            return (this.index < this.List.Count);
        }

        public void Remove(EPGString item)
        {
            try
            {
                List.Remove(item);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            index = -1;
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

When I run the fxcop tool on my code, it shows errors for "Enumerations should be strongly typed"
How can I fix the FxCop rule: Enumerations should be strongly typed in my class?
What all changes need to be done here?

Answer (score 5):

Since you are implementing a collection of strings, you should implement

```
IEnumerator<string>
```

besides IEnumerator